# How does NgModel work internally (set value initially)

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I am looking at the source code of [NgModel](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts). I understand most part of it except that how is it setting the initial `value` of input.

```
NgModel extends NgControl
```

..

```
NgControl extends NgControlDirective
```

..

`NgControlDirective` has this code:

```
get value(): any { return this.control ? this.control.value : null; }
```

So if we set `this.control.value` it automatically sets to `value` of `input`. Good.

But `this.control.setValue` is done only on update in `NgModel`.

how does it know to set the value initially.

I guess its something related to

```
this.valueAccessor = selectValueAccessor(this, valueAccessors);
```

Comment: `But this.control.setValue is done only on update in NgModel.` First call ngOnChanges will inform about first update.

Comment: I observed that too , looks legit.SimpleChanges even has a boolean to tell its first update. But not entirely sure if its the right one

Comment: That is correct , can you post an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we have the following template

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="x">
```

and in component class

```
x = 3;
```

When directive is initialized according to [life cycles hooks documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) `ngOnChange` hook is called with `currentValue` 3

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  this._checkForErrors();
  if (!this._registered) this._setUpControl();
  if ('isDisabled' in changes) {
    this._updateDisabled(changes);
  }

  if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.viewModel)) {
    this._updateValue(this.model);
    this.viewModel = this.model;
  }
}
```

Since `previousValue` equals `undefined` `this._updateValue(this.model);` method will be called.

```
private _updateValue(value: any): void {
  resolvedPromise.then(
      () => { this.control.setValue(value, {emitViewToModelChange: false}); });
}
```

where `this.control.setValue` will be called.

[image]